# Split on four alphanumerics

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
Final_Destination_8E8A-0760-5B06-68E0-68AA-7_feature_subtitle_HEB.srt
```

I need to split it on `_8E8A-`, to get `Final_Destination`. How would this be done? Here is what I have so far:

```
re.split('_\d[A-Z]{4}-',s)
```

However, this does not accurately capture the correct string prefix. This is but one example, there are many other filenames like this that I need to match this pattern.

Comment: is it always `_8E8A-`  or potentially other combinations?

Comment: Move `\d` inside of the character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `'_\d[A-Z]{4}-'` matches: underscore, then a digit, then four uppercase letters, then a dash.

This is **not** of course a match for `'_8E8A-'`, which starts fine but does **not** have after the leading underscore-then-digit four letters then a dash -- rather, what it has there is `E8A-` only 3 alphamerics, nor four, and not all letters.

So you may want to use a pattern such as `r'_\d[A-Z0-9]{3}-'` -- now **that** would match your example.  (the leading `r`, for "raw string", is not a must, but it's an excellent habit to get into to always use raw strings for RE patterns).